# How To Install dompdf (HTML to PDF converter for PHP5) on MAMP on a Mac?

Tags: php, macos, mamp, dompdf

How do I install the dompdf convertor (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) on my localhost using MAMP on my MAC computer?

I downloaded the dompdf folder to my computer but I have no idea what to do next? Do I simply copy it to a certain folder in my MAMP application folders?

The instructions on dompdf's git site says: "Download an archive of dompdf and extract it into the directory where dompdf will reside". Where should dompdf reside?

Comment: i would recommend tcpdf over dompdf

Comment: It doesn't really matter where dompdf resides, so long as you can reference it from your script, as indicated on the [usage page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage). For a quick start just place it in the root of your web server document directory and browse to the directory.